# open XMLfile in aws sagemaker

Tags: python, xml, amazon-sagemaker

I am looking for a way to display xml data and extract it to more accessible format.
I am on AWS SageMaker - connected to s3 (via the code below), but I am not sure how to simply open this xml file in my notebook.

```
my_bucket = 'my-s3-bucket'
my_file = 'my_file.xml'
s3client = boto3.client('s3')
response = s3client.get_object(Bucket=my_bucket, Key=my_file)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The body read by S3 is in bytes, in the case of XML it will be of the form `b"your_xml_content"`.

So you need to read this type of data and then, using any xml manipulation library, read in its content and navigate through it.

A complete example is this:

```py
from lxml import etree
import boto3

xml_bytes = boto3.resource('s3').Object(bucket, my_file).get()['Body'].read()
doc = etree.XML(xml_bytes)
```

---

Assuming your file is in this form:

```xml
<note>
    <to>Tove</to>
    <from>Jani</from>
    <heading>Reminder</heading>
    <body>Don't forget me this weekend!</body>
</note>
```

you can navigate the object with a simple for loop:

```py
for element in doc.iter():  # remove .iter() if you don't want the root
    print("%s - %s" % (element.tag, element.text))
```

output will be:

```
note - 
        
to - Tove
from - Jani
heading - Reminder
body - Don't forget me this weekend!
```